# jquery: suggest an autocomplete plugin that I can use

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Does anyone know if theres a jquery autocomplete library that works similar to the one here:
http://www.thetrainline.com

(try and select a station to see what i mean) The one on here is a prototype library.
Basically all the ones ive found will only match characters if they appear at the beginning of a string, for example, if i typed 'ear' it would not match the word 'hear'. However this one seems to do that.

If anyone has any ideas id  be very grateful.

Comment: The station select field seems to be different from the "From/To" fields on that site. In the station select popup, the autocomplete behavior seems to be the native browser autocomplete, which does work the way you describe. I know it's the browser's autocomplete because when I type "ru" it offers "firefox rerun script", which was a Google search I did yesterday :-)

Comment: Your right, sorry. The from and to fields are the ones i want to imitate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) from **bassistance.de**, which gives you the option of preloading all the possible data or using a server-side backend for finding matching results.

Use the `matchContains` option to match results that contain, rather than just begin with, the search string.

---

**EDIT**
Just FYI: there is now (Feb 2011) an autocomplete widget builtin to jQuery UI as of v1.8.

Comment: Thats what im using already, but it only matches characters at the beginning of a string, unless there a config option im missing?

Comment: Yes, the option `matchContains` is what you're looking for. See the `autocomplete` function documentation and look at the options list for more details. Updated answer to include this.